# How do I change the bucket fill colour in Gimp Image Editor?

Tags: gimp

How do I change the bucket fill colour in Gimp Image Editor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose We want to Fill an area in this image

[image: image1]

The bucket tool uses the foreground colour so lets change it-- Click foreground

Set new colour

[image: image2]

Click OK to accept

[image: image3]

Foreground colour now changed select bucket tool

[image: image4]

Use bucket tool -- Job Done

[image: image5]

Comment: How do I get this toolbox? When I click to get the toolbox up it is a single narrow vertical column without the bucket fill subsection your screenshot shows.

Comment: If you grab the corner of the tool box you can expand it.  When its big enough select "Windows" > "Dockable Dialogs" > "Tool Options" from the menu a new widow opens.  You can drag and drop that into the toolbox if you wish

Comment: is there a way of select foreground using menu options?

Answer (score 2):

The black square in the highlighted area defines the foreground color. This color applies to all coloring tools, like the bucket

[image]

Comment: Where do I find this window. There are no other windows in my GIMP.

Comment: @BrentonHorne: for GIMP versions prior to 2.8, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key will open and close the two additional windows: Toolbox and Layers.

Comment: CTRL + B to get toolbox. Or menu > tools > new toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is late I want to add a particular case:

## Reopen your Toolbox window

If you need to reopen your toolbox, use the key combination `Ctrl+B` or navigate through (GIMP version 2.8.14):

```
Windows > Toolbox
```

In this toolbar you can change the color by just clicking on the foreground or background color as indicated by @OrangeTux and @Warren Hill.